# matplotlib: scatter and colorbar values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data:

```
values = np.array( [0,1,2,3,4,5] )
```

I want to plot `values` as `pyplot.scatter` with different sizes and colours. Also, I want to resize the dots so the smallest dots are well visible.

If I do:

```
sc = pyplot.scatter ( pos_x, pos_y, values )
pyplot.colorbar( sc )
```

then I get the proper values and colors, but the smallest dots are *too small*. Now if I do:

```
values_scaled = (values * 2 + 1)
sc = pyplot.scatter ( pos_x, pos_y, values_scaled )
pyplot.colorbar( sc )
```

then the dots have acceptable sizes (although a bit fake) but the colorbar legend starts at 1 and ends at 11, which I don't want. I want to scale just *sizes* of the dots, but not the *values* assigned there. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) functions takes an optional keyword argument `s`, which is the *"size in points^2. It is a scalar or an array of the same length as x and y"*. So just pass your `values_scaled` array as the value of this argument and leave the colour data (the optional `c` keyword argument) as `values`, i.e.:

```
sc = pyplot.scatter(pos_x, pos_y, c=values, s=values_scaled)
```